# javascript localStorage add to table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

For an assignment I need to use javascript/jquery, but I'm new to it. I have a form with some text boxes where I can create a new animal. The animal will be added to an array called animal_list.

Animal_list will be added to localstorage and it works fine. But what I want is to load all animals from the local storage and add them to a table. The type of animals that will be stored are a cat or a dog and they also have their own table.

I have a console.log where I write the type of the animal, and this shows the right output (3 dogs, 2 cats), but they won't be added to a table.

This is my HTML code:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6">
      <h3>Honden</h3>
      <table id="dog" class="table table-hover table-striped table-condensed">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>CRN</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>DoB</th>
            <th>Gender</th>
            <th>Last Walk Date</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
      </table>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6">
      <h3>Katten</h3>
      <table id="cat" class="table table-hover table-striped table-condensed">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>CRN</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>DoB</th>
            <th>Gender</th>
            <th>Bad Habits</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
```

And this is my javascript/jQuery code:

```
$( document ).ready(function(){
    /* Eerst alle animals ophalen */
    var animal_list = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("animals"));

    if (Array.isArray(animal_list)) {
      for (var i = 0; i < animal_list.length; ++i)
      {
        /* get a specific animal from our array so we can use it's properties */
        var animal = animal_list[i];

        console.log("Loading next animal...");
        console.log("Animal type: " + animal.Type);

        if(animal.Type == "dog")
        {
          // animal is a dog

          var table = document.getElementById("#dog");

          row = table.insertRow(i+1);
          Crn = row.insertCell(0);
          Name = row.insertCell(1);
          DoB = row.insertCell(2);
          Gender = row.insertCell(3);
          Special = row.insertCell(4);

          Crn.innerHTML(animal.Crn);
          Name.innerHTML(animal.Name);
          DoB.innerHTML(animal.Dob);
          Gender.innerHTML(animal.gender);
          Special.innerHTML(animal.Special);

          save(Crn.innerHTML);
          save(Name.innerHTML);
          save(DoB.innerHTML);
          save(Gender.innerHTML);
          save(Special.innerHTML);



        }
        if(animal.Type == "cat")
        {
          // animal is a cat
          var table = document.getElementById("#cat");

          row = table.insertRow(i+1);
          Crn = row.insertCell(0);
          Name = row.insertCell(1);
          DoB = row.insertCell(2);
          Gender = row.insertCell(3);
          Special = row.insertCell(4);

          Crn.innerHTML(animal.Crn);
          Name.innerHTML(animal.Name);
          DoB.innerHTML(animal.Dob);
          Gender.innerHTML(animal.gender);
          Special.innerHTML(animal.Special);

          save(Crn.innerHTML);
          save(Name.innerHTML);
          save(DoB.innerHTML);
          save(Gender.innerHTML);
          save(Special.innerHTML);

        }
      }
    }
  });
```

The console in safari gives no error messages. I also tried to change

```
document.getElementById("#dog");
```

to (also for cat)

```
document.getElementById("dog");
```

but with no result.

Could someone help me with my problem?

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**
I fount a typo (animal.type should be animal.Type). When changed that I got an error message in my console:

> TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'table.insertRow')

(typo fixed in code)

Comment: try `console.log(Array.isArray(animal_list)));` before your `if` statement

Comment: Hint:  Glancing at this, it seems like there is a lot of manipulation of the innerds of the animal.  In real life, you do not need to chop up your pet to move it from one place to another, and in JS there is usually a way to move a data structure or a block of HTML around with a single statement that does not need to know the inner structure but rather copies the whole thing, whatever it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used jQuery to add the objects in the localStorage to a table.

This is an example for the dog-table

```
if(animal.Type == "dog")
        {
          // animal is a dog
          var table = document.getElementById("dog");

          $("#dog").append("<tr><td>" + animal.Crn + "</td><td>" + animal.Name + "</td><td>" + animal.Dob +"</td><td>" + animal.Gender + "</td><td>" + animal.Special + "</td></tr>");
        }
```